# How do I define the layout of a datasource?

Tags: c#, charts, dataset, datasource

I have a C# program that needs to display a chart with 2 serie objects. Currently I just have a dataset with 2 datatables. The two tables have the same layout. I bind the dataset to the datasource property of the chart and execute the databind() method. It only displays one serie.

I think the solution lies in defining a custom bindingcontext, but I can't seem to figure it out. Can somebody please help me? Thanks.

Below is some of my code:

```
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

        DataTable dataTable = database.Query("select sum(amount) as monthamount, month(transdate) as month from transaction where year(transdate)=" + balanceDateTimePicker.Value.Year + " group by month");
        dataSet.Tables.Add(dataTable);

        dataTable = database.Query("select sum(amount) as monthamount, month(transdate) as month from transaction where year(transdate)=" + balanceDateTimePicker.Value.AddYears(-1).Year + " group by month");
        dataSet.Tables.Add(dataTable);

        reoccuranceChart.DataSource = dataSet;
        System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series series = reoccuranceChart.Series["Series1"];
        series.XValueMember = "month";
        series.YValueMembers = "monthamount";
        series.ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Column;
        series.IsVisibleInLegend = false;

        series = reoccuranceChart.Series["Series2"];
        series.XValueMember = "month";
        series.YValueMembers = "monthamount";
        series.ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Column;
        series.IsVisibleInLegend = false;

        reoccuranceChart.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 2):

I found it. It was actually fairly simple.
All I had to do was, bind the series.points individually:

```
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

        DataTable dataTable = database.Query("select sum(amount) as monthamount, month(transdate) as month from transaction where year(transdate)=" + balanceDateTimePicker.Value.Year + " group by month");
        dataSet.Tables.Add(dataTable);

        dataTable = database.Query("select sum(amount) as monthamount, month(transdate) as month from transaction where year(transdate)=" + balanceDateTimePicker.Value.AddYears(-1).Year + " group by month");
        dataSet.Tables.Add(dataTable);

        System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series series = reoccuranceChart.Series["Now"];
        series.ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Column;
        //series.IsVisibleInLegend = false;
        series.Points.DataBind(dataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView, "month", "monthamount", "");

        series = reoccuranceChart.Series["Last year"];
        series.ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Column;
        //series.IsVisibleInLegend = false;
        series.Points.DataBind(dataSet.Tables[1].DefaultView, "month", "monthamount", "");
```

Comment: Great solution. Thanks! Also another tip for new players: If you still have a line at the top of your code like chart.DataSource = myDataSet; etc... Then remove that! As it will clobber over the top of the individual data binding as per this solution. Once I removed this line, the above solution worked. Woot!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in your reuse of your dataTable variable.  You need to create a second DataTable for the second query to prevent reassigning the first, since Add function does not copy the data in the table, it just  holds a reference to it.  Try changing:

```
dataTable = database.Query ...
```

to

```
 DataTable dataTable2 = database.Query...
```

then add that as the second table and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not the problem. In the chart I always get the result of the first Query. In the query function a new DataTable is created. It doesn't overwrite the old one.